# Including prebuilt static library in Android build system

Tags: android, makefile, native

I need to build a shared library based on a prebuilt static library.
My makefile src/android/external/mycode/Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE := libMyStatic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libStatic.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE    := libMyShared
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libMyStatic
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I build it by doing: `mmm external/mycode`
and get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libMyStatic_intermediates/libMyStatic.a', needed by `out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libMyShared_intermediates/LINKED/libMyShared.so'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/home/test/src/android'
```

If I do the following manually and run mmm again it works:

```
cp external/mycode/libStatic.a out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libMyStatic_intermediates/libMyStatic.a
```

If I make an NDK project and use this Android.mk file I think it works right away when calling the ndk-build script. So the problem has something to do with that the libMyStatic.a file is not created and copied to the intermediate folder when I use the Android Build system.
Can anyone tell me what I need to setup to make the build system copy the static library to the intermediate folder?

Comment: i come with the similar problem.Have u fix it?would u mind to share ur way with me?thx

Comment: Maybe this can help you:

[link prebuilt shared library using Android.mk][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322766/android-link-prebuilt-shared-library-so-within-jar-file-in-ndk

Answer (score 4):

modify your mk file

```
"LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libMyStatic"
```

to

```
"LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -lMyStatic
```

Answer (score 3):

Try building your static library like this.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libMyStatic
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := STATIC_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libMyStatic.a

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: It is almost complete, depending on where you place the prebuilt library. In my case it was not in external folder. I had to edit the makefiles in parent directories to make the AOSP build system aware of my lib, its dependencies and its dependants!