# Android : link prebuilt shared library (.so) within jar file in NDK

Tags: android, jar, android-ndk, shared, loadlibrary

I've a static java library compiled as a jar file.
This jar loads a .so library using System.loadLibrary.
Then another Android application project links statically the jar file.

Everything is compiled using an Android.mk file in the NDK...how can I make the shared native library being included and correctly loaded from my final application (and "seen" from the jar code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem by using these instructions in Android.mk:

$(shell cp $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/armeabi/*.so) $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATE_LIBRARIES))
LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= libMyLib

just before

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)